# ImageResizer, what is quality.ToString()?

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am trying to figure out what is exactly the quality.ToString() setting?

thank you

```
var settings = new ResizeSettings {
MaxWidth = thumbnailSize,
MaxHeight = thumbnailSize,
Format = "jpg"
};
settings.Add("quality", quality.ToString());
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inStream, outStream, settings);
resized = outStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: You have presented us some code with no context so we can only provide a guess as to what all this means. What is `quality`? What is `ResizeSettings`? What library is being used, it doesn't appear to be a standard .Net Framework component?

Answer (score 0):

It's converting the image compression "quality" value (which I'm assuming is a numerical value) to a string for the `ResizeSettings` object which (presumably) stores it as a string rather than a double.

When saving a jpg the "quality" value is a measure of how "good" the resultant image is and is in the range 1 to 100. The quality is determined by how much the image is compressed to save disk space. Jpg compression is lossy so that as you compress the image you lose data that you can't recover later.

A value of 1 is the lowest quality but most highly compressed image.

A value of 100 is the highest quality but least compressed image.

Comment: While this is probably right, how can you tell exactly what the `quality` variable is as OP doesn't show it?

Comment: @DavidG - an educated guess.

Comment: Do you have examples of those quality values?

Comment: @ChrisF So you are saying the question is unclear? :)

Comment: For a JPG in my own experience working with resizers the difference between 100 quality and 80 is 5 times the filesize. So at 100 a file can ben 15mb and at 80 it's only 3mb